# Lubuntu minimize all show desktop keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcuts

Is there a show desktop (also known as minimize all) keyboard command in Lubuntu? I looked around in lubuntu-rc.xml, but I didn't have any luck.

If there is one, and it's a Super key, then is there a way to change it? I'm using a Model M keyboard, which is pre-Super key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 13.04, "show desktop (also known as minimize all)" is found in `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`:

```
<keybind key="W-d">
  <action name="ToggleShowDesktop"/>
</keybind>
```

Try changing <kbd>W</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> to some other combination.  Only you know which combinations are free on your system.
<kbd>W</kbd> = window/super
<kbd>C</kbd> = control
<kbd>S</kbd> = shift
<kbd>A</kbd> = alt