# How can I minimize windows, only on a specific monitor?

Tags: scripts, multiple-monitors, window-manager, minimize

I have monitor and laptop screen and have a problem with the "Show desktop" function.

Laptop screen is showing widget that should stay for all the time. Main monitor is used normally.

Whenever I use keyboard shortcut (windows key + d in my case), all windows will be hidden but I only want to hide all the windows on the specific monitor.

Is this possible?

Question similar to https://superuser.com/questions/200945/how-can-i-make-the-show-desktop-function-only-hide-the-windows-on-a-specific-m, with notable difference that I ask about different OS.

Comment: This is very well possible, but requires a separate script, other then the usual "show desktop" function. Would that be ok?

Comment: Yes, it would be perfectly fine. As long as it can be triggered by keyboard shortcuts (I set `windows key` + `d` to trigger show desktop).

Comment: Cool! will post today :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm I just entered Stack for the first time within last 17 hours.

Comment: I'm slightly late to the party, but I've posted an answer , please check it.  I'd be interested to know what you guys think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Only minimize windows on one screen

The script below can be used to (only) minimize windows on the left screen *or* only on the right screen.

The script is run with either `1` or `2` as argument, depending on which screen you'd like to minimize the windows.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

scr = sys.argv[1]

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")

# find the right side of the left screen
edge = [int(s.split("x")[0]) for s in get("xrandr").split() if "+0+" in s][0]
# read the window list
wlist = [w.split() for w in get(["wmctrl", "-lG"]).splitlines()]
for w in wlist:
    # retrieve the window id and -position
    w_id = w[0]; xpos = int(w[2])
    # check the position of the window, decide action depending on arg.
    test = xpos < edge if scr == "1" else xpos >= edge
    if test:
        # check if the window is "normal" and / or minimized
        w_data = get(["xprop", "-id", w_id])
        if all([not "_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN" in w_data,
                    "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL" in w_data]):
            subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "windowminimize", w_id])
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `min_screen.py`
3. To run it:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/min_screen.py 1
   ```

   to minimize windows on the left screen, and

   ```
   python3 /path/to/min_screen.py 2
   ```

   to minimize windows only on the right screen
4. If all works fine, add it to a shortcut key

#### Notes

- The script assumes python3 is installed, but the code is not python3 specific I believe.
- The script was written on `Unity`, but unlike workspaces (viewports), handling the *screens* should not make a difference.
- The script will *not* minimize windows with pid 0 (Idle or other `tkinter`windows for example). If that is an issue, please mention. Can be solved.

#### Explanation

The script first looks up the right edge of the left screen, by looking up the string with `+0+` in the output of `xrandr`, looking like:

```
1680x1050+0+0
```

The first section, `1680`, is the widht of the left screen. Subsequently, all we have to do is look into the window list (`wmctrl -lG`) and see which of the windows is "below" or "above" `1680`, and act accordingly, minimizing with the command `xdotool windowminimize <window_id>` (or not).

Th "test" finally (`mmiz`): `xprop -id <window_id>` is to check if we are dealing with a "normal" window (instead of e.g. your desktop, which is also listed as a window), and if the window is already minimized.

*See also the comment in the script.*

### Binding the script to a keyboard shortcut

#### 1. On Lubuntu

To edit global keyboard shortcuts in Lubuntu see [Lubuntu minimize all show desktop keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298882/lubuntu-minimize-all-show-desktop-keyboard-shortcut)

In this case: save script from this answer into a file on the computer, make this file executable, open `/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` and replace

```
  <keybind key="W-d">
    <action name="ToggleShowDesktop"/>
  </keybind>
```

by

```
  <action name="Execute">
   <command>/path/to/show_desktop.py 1</command>
  </action>
```

where `/path/to/show_desktop.py`is (of course) the path to the script, and either `1` or `2` the targeted screen. ***Make the script executable***.

Restart computer to reload config.

#### 2. Unity/Gnome

***Make the script executable*** and choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```
/path/to/show_desktop.py 1
```

...to a shortcut of your choice

Comment: Works perfectly. I still need to figure out how to attach it to keyboard shortcut and "iconify windows" icon on taskbar, but that should be quite simple.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny cool! thanks for mentioning. If you won't manage with the keys, please mention. I have Lubuntu at home on a VM, I can look how to.

Comment: I added keybinding help. In the end I simply removed "iconify windows" icon as I anyway never use it.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny greatgreat. Would you mind if I remove the lubuntu tag (tonight) and add the instruction on how to add the script as a shortcut to Unity/Gnome? That way, the solution is generic, both for Lubuntu/Unity (Gnome).

Comment: Yes, that would be OK (as long as lubuntu instruction are also kept).

Answer (score 2):

#### Introduction

The script below allows user to click on a display they want, and all windows on that display will be minimized. This script is meant to be bound to a keyboard shortcut, but can run manually if so desired.

Usage is simple:

1. activate the script, your mouse cursor will turn into a cross
2. Click on any program window ( but not desktop )  on the display you wish to minimize.
3. The script will determine all the windows on that display , and minimize ( iconify ) them.

The program doesn't require any additional packages to be installed. The script has been tested on regular Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  and Lubuntu 16.04 LTS. Thanks to @JourneymanGeek for testing it on Fedora 24 with KDE as well !

#### Obtaining the script source code

The script source code can be obtained by manually copying it here, or by getting it from my [github](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/) repository. To obtain it via `git` follow these steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install git`
2. `cd /opt ; sudo git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep.git`
3. `sudo chmod -R +x sergrep`

The file will be called [minimize_display_windows.py](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/minimize_display_windows.py) . Make sure when you bind that to a keyboard shortcut to provide full path to the script. For instance, like so:

```
 python /opt/sergrep/minimize_display_windows.py
```

#### Source code

Ensure the file you save this code to, has executable permissions.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
###########################################################
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com 
# Date: July 3, 2016
# Purpose:  Minimize windows on a display which user clicks
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/793195/295286  
# Tested on: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,Lubuntu 16.04 Virtual Machine
###########################################################
# Copyright: Serg Kolo , 2016
#    
#     Permission to use,copy,modify,and distribute this software is hereby granted
#     without fee, provided that  the copyright notice above and this permission statement
#     appear in all copies.
#
#     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
#     IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
#     THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
#     LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
#     FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
#     DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#
#     https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

from gi.repository import GdkX11,Gdk
import subprocess

def run_sh(cmd):
    # reusable function to 
    # run shell commands
    # Returns stdout of the
    # process
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = proc.stdout.read().strip()
    return out 

# First,let the user click on any window
# on the monitor which they want to minimize.
# For that we need to extract integer XID of
# the window from xwininfo output.
# Basically,same as xwininfo -int | awk '/Window id/{print $4}'

user_selected = ""
for item in run_sh("xwininfo -int").split("\n"):
    if "Window id" in item:
       user_selected = item.split()[3]

# Here we basically get all the windows on the screen,
# and check if their XID matches the one user selected
# Once we find that window, we need to know to what display
# that window belongs. 
screen =  Gdk.Screen.get_default()
for window in screen.get_window_stack():
    if str(window.get_xid()) == user_selected:
       close_screen = int(screen.get_monitor_at_window(window))

# We know which display to close now. Loop over all
# windows again, and if they're on the same display
# the one that user chose - iconify it ( in X11 terminology
# that means minimize the window  )
for window in screen.get_window_stack():
    if screen.get_monitor_at_window(window) == close_screen :
       window.iconify()
```

#### Demo

A short recording of the script in action can be found on my [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlth16Zpcn8&feature=youtu.be)

#### Side-notes

Originally , I've written another script , but it can only be used in Unity and requires xdotool to be present. For those interested it is posted as [gist](https://gist.github.com/SergKolo/4c7201789df7b32b6c07015ca76ad051)

Comment: In my case I will not use it, as I always target the same monitor. But obviously +1 anyway as it also answers the question, in a noticeably different way - maybe it will be useful for others reaching it from search (including potential future me!).